# "Virtual Lists" in C# to avoid typecasting in inherited classes?

Tags: c#, inheritance, casting

Let's say I've got an abstract class called `Player`. Classes `GameAPlayer` and `GameBPlayer` inherit from `Player`. In turn, a couple of abstract classes inherit from `GameAPlayer` and `GameBPlayer` respectively.

Let's say I've got another abstract class called `Engine` which hosts `List<Player>`. Classes `GameAEngine` and `GameBEngine` both inherit from `Engine`. I know for a fact that all players in `GameAEngine` will be of type `GameAPlayer`, and that all players in `GameBEngine` will be of type `GameBPlayer`.

I cannot move `List<Player>` into `GameAEngine` and `GameBEngine` as I'm using the list in `Engine` itself.

Having to typecast `Player` into `GameAPlayer` and `GameBPlayer` every time I use the list in their respective engines just seems unclean. Is there any way I can avoid having to do this?

Comment: The simple solution is to get rid of the extra classes and add properties to the class.  You are right to question your design it is unclean and ineffective.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `Engine` to `Engine<TPlayer> where TPlayer : Player`.
Note that this will make base engines require generic type parameters everywhere; you can work around that using a non-generic interface.

Alternatively, make a `GetPlayer` method in the derived classes that does the cast, and use that instead of the base list.

Comment: The first technique makes the Engine too "Player centric". I had thought about using the second approach as well, but was trying to see if there was something better out there. I guess I'll just go that route.

Answer (score 6):

You are experiencing the pain of what is known as the "parallel hierarchies problem". Object-oriented languages historically have done a poor job of dealing with the parallel hierarchies problem.

There's lots of interesting discussion about this problem and how various techniques deal with it; there is no slam-dunk solution. You might start by reading this discussion:

http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/1621

Also, there are *lots* of Stack Overflow questions about this area as well.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parallel+hierarchies

Comment: +1 for giving me the term for the problem. Always easier to research it further once you know exactly what you're looking for :)