# C#. Can I automatically substitute derived class instead of base class

Tags: c#, inheritance, attributes, radix, derived

Language is C#.
Say i have overridden method in class A

```
    class A:B
    {
        protected override void Method(BaseClass bc)
        {
            (DerivedClass)bc.DerivedClassField = blabla;
        }
    }
```

Is there any library/language feature/etc using which i can write following:

```
    class A:B
    {
        protected override void Method(BaseClass bc)
        {
            bc.DerivedClassField = blabla;
        }
    }
```

by, for instance, adding some attribute to class A or something?
Sorry for crappy formatting.

Comment: Why is a cast not acceptable? Have you considered reviewing your design? This will essentially break the principles of OOP.

Comment: B class is supposed to be reusable, so we have a lot of methods to override in many classes. On the other hand we are sure to know which class bc would actually be(ok i know that this statement doesn't make me look like competent programmer :) ). I am considering reviewing design, but still eager to code as little as i can) Also this will make reusing B easier.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8509747/virtual-lists-in-c-sharp-to-avoid-typecasting-in-inherited-classes/8510522#8510522  See it for some ideas on how to deal with this problem.

Comment: thanks, now i know what the problem's name is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use generics to do this in a type-safe way:

```
class A<T> where T : BaseClass {
    protected virtual void Method(T bc) { ... }
}

class B : A<DerivedClass> {
    protected override void Method(DerivedClass bc) {
        bc.DerivedClassField = blabla;
    }
}
```

but this might cause other problems if you even want to use `A<T>` without knowing `T`, in which case I would use the cast (if the class structure means the cast won't fail) or redefine your object model.

Comment: hmm, didn't thought of using templates, interesting... actually this might work, thanks :)

Comment: They're not templates, they're generics. Although the syntax is the same, C# generics are completely different beasts to C++ templates

Comment: yeah i know, just bad habit of calling them so.

Answer (score 0):

You can cast `bc` as a `DerivedClass`, if you're sure that's what it is.

```
class A:B
{
    protected override void Method(BaseClass bc)
    {
        ((DerivedClass)bc).DerivedClassField = blabla;
    }
}
```